# Bug in Approved Edit Suggestions Count?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, edits

When I look at my `Review Progress` on the [StackOverflow review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), it tells me that I have edited `27` posts.

However, when I look at my `Editor Stats` on a [suggested-edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/260814), it tells me that I have had `29` edit suggestions approved.

I went through the list of `edit suggestions` I made, and it seems that I have `27` of them approved.  Why is there the discrepancy between the two?  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image: Review Progress]
[image: Editor Stats]

Comment: I guess that some posts you edited (suggested and it was approved) got deleted so they are still part of the approved suggestions count. You sure you went one by one and saw 29 (now 30) approved?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Actually, you're right - it's only 27 (now 28).  I have edited the post.
Good point about the deleted posts - that's probably it.

So, is this "difference" an intentional feature then?

Comment: Cheers! As it's most likely correct I've posted it now as answer for better clarity. :-)

Comment: Do you think a bug should be filed in order to make a better distinction between the two screens - maybe the wording should be different or a mouse-rollover explanation?  I honestly got really confused!

Comment: It's just two separate fields in the database - as it requires code change I think `feature-request` is in order. something like "Don't include deleted posts in the suggestions count under Editor Stats"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some posts you edited (suggested and it was approved) probably got deleted.

The count approved suggestions count you see under *Editor Stats* is most likely static data that is not updated when a post is deleted while the amount of edited posts used for badge calculation is "live" data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not as convinced that the difference is due to having edited questions which have since been deleted.

My editor stats show **exactly** the same difference in the counts. The **review progress** count is precisely 2 less than the ***Editor Stats*** count.

I realize that this in and of itself proves nothing. By it seems more of a stretch that both of us would have edited two posts which were then deleted. Not impossible, but still ...

I suggest continuing to keep an eye on these counts. In particular if you notice that a post you edited is deleted check to see if the difference between the counts increases.

The other aspect of the currently accepted answer which bothers me is that it implies that we would get no "credit" for an approved edit to a question or answer if it is deleted later  on. It does not seem likely to me that the review system is intended to work this way. (Of course, WTHDIK?)