# Inconsistent count of suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I look at [my suggested edit activity on my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927206/bill-woodger?tab=activity) I see “26 Suggestions”:

[image: The header of the page indicates “26 Suggestions”, with the 26 circled.]

When I look at the detail of any suggestion, and click on More, I get Editor Stats which says “Bill Woodger had 16 edit suggestions approved, and 11 edit suggestions rejected”:

[image: “Bill Woodger had 16 edit suggestions approved, and 11 edit suggestions rejected”, with 16 and 11 circled, and freehanded above it, “16 + 11 = 27”.]

The profile appears to be counting one less suggested edit than the sum of approved and rejected suggested edits. Why is the count different? In looking around, I noticed that suggestions on deleted posts are not removed. Might it be a deleted user? Or something else?

As can be seen from @animuson's Answer, I misunderstood the post I referred to (link in the comments). Although the Suggested Edit itself is not deleted, it is removed from my (or whoever's) list of Suggestions.

Comment: Edits don't change from approved to rejected if the post was deleted..

Comment: @Seth OK, I'd not even considered that, but I'm wondering why 26 is not equal to 16 + 11.

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing one of those edits was deleted.. Or rather the answer/question was.

Comment: @Seth, but I did a little search and I found something which says that Suggestions are *not* deleted when a question is deleted. Danged if I can now remember if it said the same for answers...

Comment: @Bill They're not deleted, per say. If the post they belonged to is deleted, you lose the reputation for it and it disappears from your list. So if you consider that deleted...

Comment: Rats. Missed this. Looks a bit similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132096/bug-in-approved-edit-suggestions-count

Comment: Here's the example of the Deleted (answer or question, I can't tell) but with the Suggested Edit still visible: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154949/why-are-suggested-edits-for-deleted-questions-and-answers-visible-even-with-less. Perhaps this example is the anomaly, and mine is the ordinary problem of a delete of some sort killing something from my list, but not affecting a separate count somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much like your total number of votes cast, your review stats do not decrease when posts get deleted. If you had a suggested edit which got approved or rejected, it is a permanent part of those review stats.

However, when a post with an approved suggested edit on it gets deleted, the person who suggested the edit loses the +2 reputatiom. This also removes the suggested edit from your activity list in accordance with the do-not-show-deleted-content-in-the-lists policy (unfortunately it's even hidden from moderators in this particular list. The only exception to this rule is for tag wikis and their excerpts, which don't ever get deleted. They just become orphaned when their attached tag gets destroyed.

So you *do* have 27 suggested edits. The count of 26 that you're seeing is the number of edits *visible in that list*.

The fact that there's no "removed" event in your reputation history suggests that the missing suggestion is one that was rejected, and the post was subsequently deleted. So the edit it still out there... *somewhere*... visible to users... It's just nearly impossible to actually find it without superpowers, or dev tools.

Comment: OK. I should have checked Alice's activity through the link, then I'd find that the Nov 3 Suggested Edit wasn't there, so who cares if it can be seen, the counts by now are wonky. In fact Alice's count is 10 adrift. Must have edited a lot of not-so-good posts.