# Allow moderators to see deleted posts in their activity

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, moderators, recent-activity

Sometimes as a moderator I take 'organic' moderator actions, in that I'll close a question on the front page just because I saw it, and not because it was in the moderator queue.  I've [always considered this a normal part of my job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/what-is-a-day-in-the-life-of-a-stack-overflow-moderator-like/171128#171128).

Today, [I voted to close a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612089/removing-unneeded-characters-corrupted-dna-data-program) for a few reasons.  I checked back in my activity 15 minutes later to see if the author had taken any action, only to find *the post was gone from my 'comment' activity section **even though I had left a comment***.  The reason the post was gone is that the OP deleted it.

This presented a problem.  Because there were no flags on the post, the moderator queue 'recent activity' *did not* pick up me closing that question, and because the post was deleted, I couldn't see the question anywhere else.

Luckily, I had remembered the user's name, and did a search for 'new users' with that name -- I found him after a few attempts.

In that time, he deleted his old post and he had posted a new question [that was a duplicate of his old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18612613/16587).

As a moderator, I do sometimes take organic moderator actions, and I do check up on my activity to make sure I'm following up in case the user improves their post, or something 'goes bad'.  Not being able to see deleted posts in my activity section keeps me from being able to do this, and makes it really tough if a user decides to delete a post to get around an issue, as happened here.

This is not the first time it's happened, only the most recent.

**Feature Request**:

Moderators should be able to see their comments on posts that were deleted in their activity section, and *any moderator action* should show up on either a) their moderator 'recent activity' page, or b) on their activity page under the right section.

Comment: Can you not see close-votes-on-deleted-posts in your activity -> closure votes tab (or is that included in your "anywhere else"? :)).

Comment: @Matt When a post is deleted, it's all gone.

Comment: Or even more, IMO, moderators should be able to see *anyone's* comments in the activity section of their profiles. I know we have an interface to it now, but that would seem more natural.

Answer (score 2):

If we were to do this, it would have to be something you could toggle that defaults to off and resets. Even developers don't see deleted stuff in those two tabs when looking at a user, they have to use the special comment (mod -> info -> comments) tool from the user's profile mod menu in order to do it.

This would have shown you the comment you were looking for (but, well, so would the comment tool once you realized it was gone), but in addition to a *whole lot* of other rubbish and ratchets that you probably *don't* want to see when you're just going back in your history, because it's just that - almost all deleted junk you don't need to care about any more. I can see the convenience of seeing it inline, I just want to be sure you guys can *make it stop* when you *don't* need to see it.

I like the idea of better journaling any instance where you weren't the *last* needed vote in order to make something happen (closing, delete, reopening). If you were indeed the *last* vote, then it's more coincidence than 'a mod did this'.

Note - not throwing a status tag on this, as I have no idea how complicated or expensive it would be to implement. These are just my thoughts on what you proposed.

Comment: Could we get something like that for other pieces of activity? I [recently realized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195390) that if a suggested edit gets rejected, and the post it's attached to gets deleted, the suggestion basically falls off the face of the planet. I haven't found any way to track them down.